# Laravel global scope for a model based on parent relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to write global scope for models to be used as the default for `index` queries. *note I am using default Laravel jetstream boilerplate with --teams*. I believe the view, update, delete, etc., authorization may be handled by model policies. Here, I want to list elements the user owns on the current team for all related models.

My `Project::class belongsTo(Team::class)` and has global scope

```php
static::addGlobalScope('owned', function (Builder $builder) {
    $builder->where('team_id', Auth::user()->currentTeam->id);
});
```

`Project::class hasMany(Note::class)`

I wish to have global scope listing only `Notes` which belong to `Projects` which belong to the Team user is a member of.

```php
static::addGlobalScope('owned', function (Builder $builder) {
    $builder->whereHas('project', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('team_id', Auth::user()->currentTeam->id);
    });
});
```

Is it the correct approach? What about deeper relations where Note may have another hasMany or any other relations; or should I query all Notes through User->Team->Projects->Notes

Comment: Did you consider using hasOneThrough?

Comment: I did, however i am trying to use it in the admin panel where the resource is the model I'm trying to apply global scope.